# how to fill edit text box with transpert grey

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hello I have a program and I have an edit text box which the user will fill his name. How can I set a default text , light gray colored that says 'please enter your name' and when the user enter a word it will be deleted and replaced in the word he written?
I hope u understand my English, I want it to be like the gmail edit text that 'username' is written in it.

Comment: Try yourEditText.setHint("Please enter your name");  `setHint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.

This is the easiest way, through the class...

```
myTextView.setHint("My conditional hint");
```

Or you can have the following in your XML page under your text view

```
android:hint="Write Caption"
```

or in your graphical layout you can scroll down to hint, etc...

Please note that this is very basic stuff and a quick Google can help you!

Comment: Please close off this by selecting the answer you found helpful so that it taken off from list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:hint="Please enter your name"` in your layout.xml   like this

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Please enter your name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

or by Java code in your class file like this:

```
EditText nameEditText = (EditText)FindViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
nameEditText.setHint("Please enter your name");
```